# Uncertainty about segmentation-fault error

Tags: c, error-handling, stack

I'm working on a stack ADT and I'm trying to execute the stack_push (pushing an item on top of a stack). Note, instead of a stack with integers, I'm working with strings. This is what I have:

```
char *strdup(const char *s) {
  char *new = malloc((strlen(s) + 1) * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(new, s);
  return new;
}

void stack_push(const char *str, struct stack *s) {
  assert(s);
  assert(str);
  char *copied_str = strdup(str);
  if (s->len == s->maxlen) {
    s->maxlen *= 2;
    s->data = realloc(s->data, (sizeof(s->data) +
                       ((strlen(str) + 1) * sizeof(char))));
  }
  strcpy(s->data[s->len], copied_str);
  s->len += 1;
}
```

Also, my stack implementation is simply:

```
struct stack {
  char **data;
  int len;
  int maxlen;
};
```

When I run this, my strcpy function (the third to last line of stack_push) is giving me a memory error, specifically segmentation-fault-on-null-address, and I have no idea why this is happening. I already have the string ADT included in my code so functions like strlen, strcmp, and even strcpy, should be in here already.

Can anyone help me figure out my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The size passed to your `realloc` call is incorrect.  Since you want to be able to store `maxlen` strings in `s->data`, the size calculation should make use of that variable.  Specifically, the size to allocate should be `sizeof(*s->data) * s->maxlen`

Comment: I suspect `strcpy(s->data[s->len], copied_str);` shoudl also become `s->data[s->len] = copied_str;`

Comment: And `copied_str` is pointless, since you could just as easily write `s->data[s->len] = strdup(str);`